# Error cloning github repo

Tags: github, terminal

Trying to clone a repo on Github, using Terminal on Mac OS 10.11.6. I'm using SSH and getting the following error:

```
git clone git@github.com:myaccount/ng2-workshop-review.git
Cloning into 'ng2-workshop-review'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, strange. When I use the copy button next to the provided link (after hitting the 'clone and download' button and SSH), and and drop that into terminal, rather than actually drag mouse over the link to copy it, it worked! How peculiar...

Answer (score 0):

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

This problem is probably caused error of SSH configuration or lack of a defined SSH key for github. If you wont use this method for cloning (and other operations), first you must correct create and configure SSH key for github, maybe this page help you: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

If you don't wont make SSH key, you can always clone repository by HTTPS:

```
git clone https://github.com/myaccount/ng2-workshop-review.git
```

Look on: https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository/

Comment: Thanks. Funny enough it literally worked when I used the copy button rather than copy and paste :) Strange!